# The purple section is too tall in the GPU graphic of android monitor when going from Activity A to Activity B

Tags: android, transition

I use scene transition and share element in both activity(there is an image view in the `RecyclerView` of Activity A,and it has same transition name with the image view in activity B). When I want to jump from A to B ,it's behavior is not so good.

Then I see the GPU profile in android monitor,show as below:
[image: GPU profile]

Then I see the [android developer document](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/dev-options-rendering.html), it said:

> Android 4.0 and higher: The purple section of the bar represents the time spent transferring resources to the render thread.

How can I reduce the spent time of `XFer`?